# How to set the value of xcc.txn.compatible property when working with .NET XCC library?

Tags: c#, .net, marklogic

I am using Marklogic XCC connector of version 8.0 and my database is Marklogic server 6.0. I get this exception **RequestServerException** while submitting a query and if transactionMode is also changed.

I searched [this](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4?print=yes) out and found that there is a issue with compatibility of XCC 8.0 with previous versions of marklogic server.

Solution I got is to set **xcc.txn.compatible** property to **true**. Now I can't find this property or namespace in any marklogic dll(e.g. Marklogic.Xcc).

Any suggestion how and where I can set this property??
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I've asked around and it seems that you can't specify that property with the .NET XCC library. You have a couple options:

- Use the [XCC version 6 library](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/xcc/6.0) with MarkLogic 6
- Upgrade to MarkLogic 8 and use the XCC version 8 library
- Instead of using XCC, use the REST API. You can make HTTP calls with .NET and get a lot of functionality out of the box this way. There isn't an official .NET wrapper for the REST API, but there is a [community project](https://developer.marklogic.com/labs/mldotnet) that you could use as a starting point (and it was started using MarkLogic 6).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But are sure about this?? Can you please site the source where you have read this.

Comment: I work at MarkLogic and asked around internally. Nothing public source that I can point to.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can specify that value on the command-line with a `-D` option. That translates to a System property within the code. I think Environment variables are translated into System properties as well. Maybe try setting an system-wide environment variable called `xcc.txn.compatible` with value `true`?

HTH!

Comment: :- Tried that but didn't worked.Still getting that exception. Thanks for the help anyways.